# Represent a class as a dict or list

Tags: python, structure, idioms

I've classes that is used for getting data from one system, making some modifications and then outputting them into another system. Which usually goes the way of converting it into a `dict` or a `list` after I've made all the necessary conversions.

So far what I've done is that I've made two methods called `as_dict()` and `as_list()` and used that whenever I need that representation.

But I'm curious if there's a way to be able to do `dict(instance_of_my_class)` or `list(instance_of_my_class)`.

I've been reading up on [magic methods](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html) and it seems as if this is not possible?

And some simple sample code to work with:

```
class Cost(object):
    @property
    def a_metric(self):
        return self.raw_data.get('a_metric', 0) * 0.8

    [..]
    # Repeat for various kinds of transformations

    def as_dict(self):
        return {
          'a_metric': self.a_metric,
          [...]
        }
```

Comment: why do you need to transform the class into a dictionary/list? every class has a built in __dict__, that is where class attributes are stored internally, maybe it is enough to just store that.

Comment: There is `vars()` built-in which is basically the same as `obj.__dict__`.

Comment: @theAlse mainly for converting it for updates in databases or for simple conversion to json

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? If so you have to define a `__iter__` method that yield's key-value pairs:

```
In [1]: class A(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:        self.pairs = ((1,2),(2,3))
   ...:     def __iter__(self):
   ...:         return iter(self.pairs)
   ...:     

In [2]: a = A()

In [3]: dict(a)
Out[3]: {1: 2, 2: 3}
```

---

Also, it seems that `dict` tries to call the `.keys` / `__getitem__` methods before `__iter__`, so you can make `list(instance)` and `dict(instance)` return something completely different.

```
In [4]: class B(object):
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:        self.d = {'key':'value'}
    ...:        self.l = [1,2,3,4]
    ...:     def keys(self):
    ...:         return self.d.keys()
    ...:     def __getitem__(self, item):
    ...:         return self.d[item]
    ...:     def __iter__(self):        
    ...:         return iter(self.l)
    ...:     

In [5]: b = B()

In [6]: list(b)
Out[6]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [7]: dict(b)
Out[7]: {'key': 'value'}
```

Comment: @gaqzi -- It seems that `dict` tries to call `.keys` before calling `__iter__` so you can make `list(instance)` and `dict(instance)` return something completely different if you need to :)

Comment: Awesome!! :D Thanks for this. Im developing a structure of diferent database libraries (classes) that inherits from an abstract class Database whose receive a map for configuration and authentication.